# Copy Activity Issue for Incremental part

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working on incremental data from S4. So i have designed the pipeline and it is not doing incremental part.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgrYh.png)

In source side :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mit5b.png)

In Target side

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZwWL.png)

The Pipeline running succesfully but incrmental part is not working.I decided to delete the latest records and upload i am getting error after apply this formula in sink :

Details
ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near 'count'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near 'count'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect syntax near 'count'.,},],'

I am getting error for copy activty :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfCxb.png)

Please advise

Regards
Rohit

Comment: Could you share the configurations in Lookup activity Destinations table name and current_date_up_date? Also, share the functionality of stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks I got the solution and managed it and it is working fine

Comment: Post you solution as answer so that it can help community members having same issue.